# How to make this as Array?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I am trying to put my data inside Highchart Library. There it is showing sample as following code.

```
series: [
    {
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    },
    {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    },
    {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }
]
```

So i need it to dynamically put as an Array for dynamic input (from PHP). So how can i make it a Javascript Array?

To use, for example:

```
series: myArray;
```

So how can i implement it with an array?

```
var myArray = new Array();
and .. ???
```

Comment: `series` is a javascript array already. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @DavidHedlund So how can i add dynamically from PHP ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the array literal (`[]`) as in the example:

```
var myArray = [
    {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    },
    {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    },
    {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }
];
```

which is equivalent to:

```
var myArray = [];
myArray[0] = { name: 'John', data: [5,3,4,7,2] };
myArray[1] = { name: 'Jane', data: [2,2,3,2,1] };
myArray[2] = { name: 'Joe', data: [3,4,4,3,5] };
```

So `myArray` is an array of objects. These objects have two properties, `name` and `data`, where the latter is another array holding numbers.

To send data from PHP to Javascript, you can create [JSON](http://www.json.org/) from your PHP arrays using the [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function. For example, in your PHP, you can have something like this:

```
<?php

$myArray = array(
    array('name' => 'John', data => array(5,3,4,7,2)),
    array('name' => 'Jane', data => array(2,2,3,2,1)),
    array('name' => 'Joe', data => array(3,4,4,3,5)),
);

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var myArray = <?php echo json_encode($myArray); ?>
</script>
```

Comment: This is same as above array `serie`. I mean i just want to add the values dynamically from PHP. How to implement that Array with Javascript+PHP?

Comment: @4lvin Added some help about using JSON.

Answer (score 1):

If the source array is in PHP, then I would serialize it to JSON and use it directly as a JS object:

http://ch2.php.net/json

Something like:

```
var jsData = <?php echo json_encode($your stuff); ?>;
```

**EDIT**: Improved example

Comment: @4lvin What about showing some effort? You've got a lot of useful hints, JSON, `json_encode()` from Pedro and me. I'd consider your question answered.

Answer (score -1):

I would Highly recommend JSON. As it maintains a Name:Value Pair.